# Relating two lists to a dict key

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am trying to relate two lists to the same dict key; Then display the lists in a html table. I do not know if I am choosing an incorrect method in which to store the lists, or if I am messing up the configuration of for loops required to show the lists. Wondering if anyone can help.

What I have so far:

What I want to relate to: KeyA
Two lists: ListA and ListB.

Storing:

```
listA = [1,2,3,4]
listB = [A,B]
keys = {}
lists = []
lists.append([ListA,ListB])
keys.setdefault(KeyA, []).append(lists)
```

Displaying:

```
{% for option in keys %}
    <tr class = 'collapse level1' data-depth="1" >
        <td class ='site_device'> </td>
        <td class = 'site_device' > {{option}}</td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>

        {% for list_holder in keys[option] %}
            {% for lists in list_holder %}
                {% for v1 in lists %}
                    <tr class = 'collapse level2' data-depth="2" >
                        <td class ='site_device'></td>
                        <td class ='site_device'></td>
                        <td class ='site_device'>{{ v1 }}</td>
                        <td class ='site_device'></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This method gives:

```
<tr class = 'collapse level1' data-depth="1" >
    <td class ='site_device'> </td>
    <td class = 'site_device' > KeyA</td>
    <td class ='site_device'></td>
    <td class ='site_device'></td>
    <tr class = 'collapse level2' data-depth="2" >
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'>[1, 2, 3, 4]</td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = 'collapse level2' data-depth="2" >
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'>['A','B']</td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to aim for:

```
<tr class = 'collapse level1' data-depth="1" >
    <td class ='site_device'> </td>
    <td class = 'site_device' > KeyA</td>
    <td class ='site_device'></td>
    <td class ='site_device'></td>
    <tr class = 'collapse level2' data-depth="2" >
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'> 1 </td>
        <td class ='site_device'> A </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = 'collapse level2' data-depth="2" >
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'> 2 </td>
        <td class ='site_device'> B </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = 'collapse level2' data-depth="2" >
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'> 3 </td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = 'collapse level2' data-depth="2" >
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'> 4 </td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it but you have embedded your list one level too far.

So, replace

```py
lists.append([listA,listB])
```

by

```py
lists.append(listA)
lists.append(listB)
```

Something else, why use this?:

```py
keys.setdefault(KeyA, []).append(lists)
```

instead of

```py
keys.setdefault(KeyA, lists)
# or even
keys['KeyA']=lists
```

Which is far more readeable.

For the other issue, a possibility is to loop on something like:

```py
{% for option in keys %}
    <tr class = 'collapse level1' data-depth="1" >
        <td class ='site_device'> </td>
        <td class = 'site_device' > {{option}}</td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        <td class ='site_device'></td>
        {% for list_holder in keys[option] %}
            {% for i in range(list_holder[0]|length) %}
                    <tr class = 'collapse level2' data-depth="2" >
                        <td class ='site_device'></td>
                        <td class ='site_device'></td>
                        <td class ='site_device'>{{ list_holder[0][i] }}</td>
                        <td class ='site_device'>{{ list_holder[1][i] }}</td>
                    </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Of course as both lists don't have the same size, it will raise IndexError(s). So make sure both lists have the same size.

Comment: Works perfectly when using print. However when i try to use it in html I get this error:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'for' ........  For the line: {% for i in range(max([len(x) for x in list_holder])) %}

Answer (score 1):

`append` adds a new element to your list, so you end up with a 3-level list (`lists` is `[[[1, 2, 3, 4], ['A', 'B']]]` instead of `[[1, 2, 3, 4], ['A', 'B']]`)

try using `extend` instead:

```py
lists.extend([ListA,ListB])
```

(or alternatively, append one by one)

```py
lists.append(ListA)
lists.append(ListB)
```

Comment: Thank you, that eliminates 1 problem. Now when i display 'v1' i get 6 rows 
first row: 1
second row:  2
...
last row: B. 
Is there any way to display them as i showed in the original post? So the first elements of listA and listB are on the same row.